# How to properly install @angular/fire at angular?

Tags: angular, firebase, compiler-errors, angularfire

I am trying to install authentication, firestore, hosting, realtime database of firebase at my angular application. I have used

```
ng add @angular/fire
```

but I get error

```
 Package install failed.
E:\xampfolder\hci project\Organic Food\orgshop\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\hostReportError.js:4
    setTimeout(function () { throw err; }, 0);
                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
    at Object.error (E:\xampfolder\hci project\Organic Food\orgshop\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\schematic-command.js:432:47)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (E:\xampfolder\hci project\Organic Food\orgshop\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:205:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.error (E:\xampfolder\hci project\Organic Food\orgshop\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:156:26)
    at Subscriber._error (E:\xampfolder\hci project\Organic Food\orgshop\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:92:26)
    at Subscriber.error (E:\xampfolder\hci project\Organic Food\orgshop\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:72:18)
    at TapSubscriber._error (E:\xampfolder\hci project\Organic Food\orgshop\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\tap.js:75:26)
    at TapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (E:\xampfolder\hci project\Organic Food\orgshop\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:72:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.SimpleOuterSubscriber.notifyError (E:\xampfolder\hci project\Organic Food\orgshop\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\node_modules\rxjs\internal\innerSubscribe.js:72:26)
    at SimpleInnerSubscriber._error (E:\xampfolder\hci project\Organic Food\orgshop\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\node_modules\rxjs\internal\innerSubscribe.js:30:21)
    at SimpleInnerSubscriber.Subscriber.error (E:\xampfolder\hci project\Organic Food\orgshop\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:72:18)
```

I am using

```
Angular CLI: 13.1.4
Node: 14.15.5
Package Manager: npm 6.14.11
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 13.1.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... localize, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1301.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.1.4
@angular-devkit/core            13.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.1.4
@angular/cli                    13.1.4
@angular/fire                   7.2.0
@schematics/angular             13.1.4
rxjs                            7.4.0
typescript                      4.5.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try  `npm install @angular/fire firebase --save`